# What is the best way to display the data on jQuery that will look like console with scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had to make this text adventure game for school project. I would like to make my game display the text in div box, using jQuery, that feels like you were typing in a terminal console with the scrolling bar when the text append.

Which one is the best for me using

1. `append()`
2. `insertBefore/After()`
3. `text()`
4. `addClass()`
5. `appendTo()`
6. `clone()`